# Connect PyCharm to AWS cloud9

Tags: ssh, pycharm, aws-cloud9

I want to connect my PyCharm IDE to the AWS Cloud9 in my account using an OpenSSH compatible SSH client with a key pair that can be used for public key authentication. The objective is to extend the PyCharm IDE's capabilities.

For VS Code IDE - the connection to AWS Cloud9 can be easily setup following the instruction in this link : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/field-notes-use-aws-cloud9-to-power-your-visual-studio-code-ide/

I am looking for similar connection between PyCharm and Cloud9.

---

I have tried PyCharm professional version - Remote Development feature which is in beta version.
The SSH connection needs to read from my local ~/.ssh folder the config file and the ssm-proxy.sh file because AWS Session Manager (AWS SSM) information is in the ssm-proxy.sh file.
But it didn't work.
Please note that I already have a Cloud9 (EC2) instance up and running and the ssh id_rsa public key is already added to my cloud9 setup.

Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: "But it didn't work" is not enough information. HOW did it not work? Was there an error; if so, what does it say?

Comment: Unable to connect is the error message.